# datepicker scrolls to top after selection (dialog) - IE

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm having problems with datepickers inside a dialog modal. After each date selection, the page scrolls to the top of the dialog which is very annoying.

Using jQuery 1.9 & jQuery-ui 1.10 and tried both minified & normal versions.

Tried the following

```
(F?" ui-priority-secondary":"")+'" href="#">'+q.getDate()+"</a>")+"</td>"
```

to

```
(F?" ui-priority-secondary":"")+'" href="javascript:;">'+q.getDate()+"</a>")+"</td>"
```

and

```
href="javascript:return false;"
```

But none seem to work.

Comment: Simply try `##` instead of `#`

Comment: no luck - still scrolls to the top

Comment: Could you post some code, maybe in a jsFiddle? Are you sure it's the datepicker causing the problem, not the opening of the modal dialog?

Comment: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/5498 - just tried to get the latest 1.10.4 but now it shows the date after selection, pauses for 1 second and then scrolls to the top.

Comment: i downgraded to ui 1.9.2 and seems to not have the issue - ill stick with that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `javascript:void(0);` or read about `event.preventDefault()` if you are using jquery its the easy way to do it, more information https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault

if you are using a `#` without the prevent.default always its gonna take you to the top of the browser `javascript:;` its gonna create and error in javascript script.

read also this [event.preventDefault() vs. return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false) and read the comments about `return false;`

Comment: sorry but cant help without you entire code what its `(F?` doing? and yes thats the answer your problem should be in other place...